# How do I expanding a specific node in a Flex Tree control

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

This is the code im using...

```
dp = CategoryParser.createDataProvider( Application.application.categoriesmanager.categoryBaseList);

var xList:XMLList = dp..category.(hasOwnProperty("@categoryid") && @categoryid == 1491);

categoryTree.expandItem(xList, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are tow ways:

`tree.openItems = xList;` details here http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/01/15/expanding-nodes-in-a-flex-tree-control-using-the-openitems-property/

Or in other case this one

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/12/02/expanding-and-collapsing-flex-tree-nodes-using-the-expanditem-and-expandchildrenof-methods/